# Schema changes not updated in MS Access front end linked to the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I created a new table in SQL server using SQL Server Management Studio but the MS Access front end linked to the database was not updated.

I tried reopening Access but still the new tables cannot be found. Yet when I check the SQL Server database they are there.

My tables in Access are linked to the database so *I assumed any table or changes made in the SQL server database would be reflected in the Access front end*.  When I run a query in Access looking for the tables nothing is found.  Another bit of information is when I right click and press view dependencies it says unable to view dependencies because

> "unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type
>   'System.string'"

Something is maybe wrong with the way i save the query but I am not sure.

Comment: what do you mean by 'made query' .. but then you say 'new tables'. Are you saying you created new tables using Management Studio? and Access just can't see those new tables?

Comment: It might help if you listed the versions of SQL Server and Access you're using.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I made a query in my access front end that essentially said SELECT * FROM newtablename, to see if I could pull up the new table using the query.  I was given the SQL code to add a table, I thought I had to implement it through a query. If it helps the code for one of the new tables is :

Comment: All you need to do is run the linking process again, per my answer below. What you're expecting does not automagically happen.

Comment: also the versions of Access is 2010 and the SQL management studio is 2008 @Paul Sasik

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption:

> I assumed any table or changes made in the SQL server database would
>   be reflected in the Access front end

...**is not** correct. Access does not automatically re-link when the SQL Server's schema changes, and it really can't. You're expecting Access assumes the data models between SQL Server and Access are the same. Even if your table and column names are exactly the same there are still differences to deal with since the data types have some differences. So, even in the best-case scenario Access does not have enough info to automatically re-link.

When you modify the SQL Server db you have to re-link from Access. Here's [an article with some code](http://blogs.office.com/2012/08/03/automatically-relink-microsoft-access-tables/) that will allow you to do that quickly but note that you still have to launch it manually. And beware, as mentioned above, linking isn't that straightforward. If you use an automated method for linking the process will have to make some decisions, some of which make take you by surprise.

Comment: I went through the relinking process and the tables still haven't appeared.  Do you think it could somehow be related to the error that occurs when I try to view the dependecies?

Comment: No. Did you see your new SQL Server table(s) in the relinking process? If you just run a re-link, the process will only update the tables you already have linked.

Comment: Do I manually create tables in access that I then link  to the tables on the SQL database?

Comment: @VictoriaJay if one of the answers helped please mark it as the accepted answer. If you found another answer please post it and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the management of linked tables in access to be administratively tedious.  In order to make my life simpler I have used the functions below that can be called to update the linked tables in access. This will take care of updating the structure of any changed table in SQL.  Adding values to the SetTableNames function will bring in new tables

```
Private mstrTableNames(100) As String
Private const gcSQLDB as string = "MySQLServer"
Private const gcUserID as string = "SQLUserName"
Private const gcUserPassword as string = "SQLPassword"
Private const gcLiveDSN as string = "DSN"
Private const gcEmpty as string = ""

Public Function LinkLiveTables() As Boolean

   Dim tdfLinked As TableDef
   Dim strConnect As String
   Dim intLoop As Integer

   'Remove all non system tables from the application: 
   ' !!!NB Add other exclusions so as to not delete tables that are not linked!!!
    For Each tdfLinked In CurrentDb.TableDefs
      If Left(tdfLinked.Name, 2) <> "MS" Then
        If Left(tdfLinked.Name, 7) <> "tblTemp" Then
         CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete tdfLinked.Name
        End If
      End If
   Next

   'Create a linked table that points to SQL Server
   strConnect = "ODBC;DATABASE=" & gcSQLDB & ";UID=" & gcUserID & _
                ";PWD=" & gcUserPassword & ";DSN=" & gcLiveDSN
   SetTablesNames
   For intLoop = 1 To 100
      If mstrTableNames(intLoop) = gcEmpty Then GoTo ProcExit
      Set tdfLinked = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(mstrTableNames(intLoop))
      With tdfLinked
         .Connect = strConnect
         .SourceTableName = "dbo." & mstrTableNames(intLoop)
      End With
      CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tdfLinked
   Next

ProcExit:
   MsgBox "Connection to the LIVE tables was successful.", vbInformation
   Exit Function
ProcError:
   MsgBox "Link to LIVE tables Failed." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
          "Error Number : " & Err.number & vbCrLf & _
          "Error Description : " & Err.Description, vbCritical
End Function

Private Sub SetTablesNames()

   mstrTableNames(1) = "tblMoistureHist"
   mstrTableNames(2) = "tblRawMaterials"
    ' ... add the additional table that you need as mstrTableNames(n) = "tablename"
End Sub
```